# Why do I get the wrong count assigned to a variable?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to store the highest count to a variable.

It shows the right counts when I loop through my array but the assignment to the high count variable  seems to be the count of the last item checked in the array.

```
def calculate_word_frequency(content, line_number)
  looper = 0
  wordCounter = ""
  #CREATE AN ARRAY FROM EACH LINE
  myArray = content.split
  #LOOP THROUGH ARRAY COUNTING INSTANCES OF WORDS
  while looper < myArray.length 
    p myArray[looper]
    wordCounter = myArray[looper]
    puts myArray.count(wordCounter)
    if highest_wf_count  < myArray.count
      highest_wf_count = myArray.count
    end
    looper +=1
  end
  puts highest_wf_count
end
```

Comment: I really have a hard time understanding what this is supposed to be doing. You know you can iterate through an array using `array.each`, right? Using `while` and a counter is a really messy way of doing the same.

Comment: Can you give sample input and output?

Your code is a bit chaotic (while instead of each, camelCase and snake_case mixed) and does not run (highest_wf_count is undefined) as is.  Perhaps you can clean it up a bit?

Comment: And what is the line_number parameter for?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". We also need the minimal input data and expected output so we can test the code and compare the results to your expectations. As is you're making it harder for us to help you, which isn't what you want to do.

Comment: In Ruby we don't use camel case for variables; Instead use snake_case. It'sAReadabilityThingAndRubyIsn'tJava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to count the frequency of something, and get the maximum value, is all over Stack Overflow.

I'd do it like this:

```
def word_frequency(content)
  content 
  .split 
  .each_with_object(
    Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
  ) { |w, h|
    h[w] += 1 
  }
end

def max_frequency(content)
  word_frequency(content)
  .max_by{ |k, v| v }
end

word_frequency('a') # => {"a"=>1}
word_frequency('a b') # => {"a"=>1, "b"=>1}
word_frequency('a b a') # => {"a"=>2, "b"=>1}
word_frequency('a b a c a b') # => {"a"=>3, "b"=>2, "c"=>1}

max_frequency('a b a c a b') # => ["a", 3]
```

I'm using a basic [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split), which only splits on whitespace.

```
'a b'.split # => ["a", "b"]
'a. b'.split # => ["a.", "b"]
```

That's very naive and will return only breaks in whitespace, not true words. There are lots of questions about how to improve the results on SO.

[`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is similar to [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), only more convenient. It'll be your friend.

[`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) is similar to [`max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) but more convenient/faster when working with complex objects that you need to dig into to get the value you are comparing.

Things to do:

- Reduce your code into smaller chunks. This is important for debugging and for testing/maintenance.
- Learn the core-library well, especially [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html), [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html), [IO](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html) and [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html). You'll use them more than any other classes/modules in Ruby if you do general programming.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at these two lines:

```
puts myArray.count(wordCounter)

highest_wf_count = myArray.count
```

The `myArray.count(...)` calls a method `count(something)` that counts items that equal to the given 'something'.
The `myArray.count` is a property that returns number of items in `myArray`.

Most probably you wanted to call the first one, then inspect it, compare, and gather max from these values, something like:

```
countingresult = myArray.count(wordCounter)
puts countingresult

if highest_wf_count  < countingresult
  highest_wf_count = countingresult
end
```

As you have it now, the compare-and-gather-max looks at constant length of the array.

BTW. I just noticed what `wordCounter` **really** is. Believe me, it took me three rechecks to understand. Name of that variable is really misleading. When you're doing some cleanups, please change it to something like "currentWord" or "nextWordToCheck" etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the highest number a word occurs in a string, you can try something like

```
def calculate_word_frequency(content)
  frequencies = content.split(/\s/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word, counts|
    counts[word] += 1
  end
  sorted = frequencies.to_a.sort do |(_, count_a), (_, count_b)|
    count_b <=> count_a
  end
  max_word_and_count = sorted.first
  max_word_and_count.last
end
```

or a shorted version which does not need to sort (in case you are really only interested in the max count):

```
def calculate_word_frequency(content)
  max = 0
  frequencies = content.split(/\s/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |word, counts|
    count = counts[word] += 1
    max = count > max ? count : max
  end
  max
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question has been answered, so I'd like to suggest an alternative approach, using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), that depends on the information that is needed.

```
str = "Bill thought the other Bill should pay the bill or Sue should pay the bill"
```

**Just the maximum frequency**

If you only want the frequency of a word that appears the maximum number of times, you could write the following.

```
def calculate_word_frequency(content)
  content.split.
          group_by(&:itself).
          map { |_, arr| arr.size }.
          max
end

calculate_word_frequency str
  #=> 3
```

[Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) was introduced in Ruby v2.2. For earlier versions, replace `group_by(&:itself)` with `group_by { |e| e }`.

Note that `content.split` has the same effect as `content.split /\s+/`.

**Word with maximum frequency and its frequency**

If, in addition, you want to know which word had the greatest frequency, modify the above as follows.

```
def calculate_word_frequency(content)
  content.split.
          group_by(&:itself).
          map { |word, arr| [word, arr.size] }.
          max_by(&:last)
  end

calculate_word_frequency str
  # => ["the", 3]
```

**Case indifference**

If you want "Bill" and "bill" to be regarded as the same word, change `content.split` to `content.downcase.split` or modify the above as follows.

```
def calculate_word_frequency(content)
  content.split.
          group_by { |word| word.downcase }.
          map { |word, arr| [word, arr.size] }.
          max_by(&:last)
  end

calculate_word_frequency str
  #=> ["bill", 4]
```

**Disregard punctuation**

If you want to disregard punctuation, do it first, as follows.

```
def calculate_word_frequency(content)
  content.delete(".,:;'\"?!").
          downcase.
          split.
          group_by(&:itself).
          map { |word, arr| [word, arr.size] }.
          max_by(&:last)
  end

str = "Bill said \"Bill, pay the bill!\" Bif said 'Sue' should've payed the bill."  
calculate_word_frequency str
  #=> ["bill", 4]
```